R matrix calculation benchmarks much slower on M3 Mac vs 2019 Intel
I ran some benchmarks comparing my new M3 Pro Macbook Pro to my older 2019 Intel Macbook Pro, and I'm getting some very poor timing results for matrix operations. Is there an explanation for this, either due to the hardware itself, or the way I set up the computer?
For example:

Intel: 2,500 x 2,500 cross-product matrix (b = a' * a): 0.0902 (sec).
M3: 2,500 x 2,500 cross-product matrix (b = a' * a): 7.53 (sec).

Intel Macbook Info
2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
> devtools::session_info(info="all")
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.3.2 (2023-10-31)
 os       macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
 system   x86_64, darwin20

 [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library

 BLAS           /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
 lapack         /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
 lapack_version 3.11.0

M3 Macbook Info
version  R version 4.4.0 (2024-04-24)
 os       macOS Sonoma 14.4.1
 system   aarch64, darwin20
 

BLAS           /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
 lapack         /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
 lapack_version 3.12.0

Intel Results
> benchmarkme::benchmark_std(runs = 10)

# Programming benchmarks (5 tests):
    3,500,000 Fibonacci numbers calculation (vector calc): 0.174 (sec).
    Grand common divisors of 1,000,000 pairs (recursion): 0.577 (sec).
    Creation of a 3,500 x 3,500 Hilbert matrix (matrix calc): 0.216 (sec).
    Creation of a 3,000 x 3,000 Toeplitz matrix (loops): 1.07 (sec).
    Escoufier's method on a 60 x 60 matrix (mixed): 3.05 (sec).
# Matrix calculation benchmarks (5 tests):
    Creation, transp., deformation of a 5,000 x 5,000 matrix: 0.503 (sec).
    2,500 x 2,500 normal distributed random matrix^1,000: 0.146 (sec).
    Sorting of 7,000,000 random values: 0.627 (sec).
    2,500 x 2,500 cross-product matrix (b = a' * a): 0.0902 (sec).
    Linear regr. over a 5,000 x 500 matrix (c = a \ b'): 0.047 (sec).
# Matrix function benchmarks (5 tests):
    Cholesky decomposition of a 3,000 x 3,000 matrix: 0.413 (sec).
    Determinant of a 2,500 x 2,500 random matrix: 0.495 (sec).
    Eigenvalues of a 640 x 640 random matrix: 0.672 (sec).
    FFT over 2,500,000 random values: 0.233 (sec).
    Inverse of a 1,600 x 1,600 random matrix: 0.575 (sec).

M3 Results
> benchmarkme::benchmark_std(runs = 10)

# Programming benchmarks (5 tests):
    3,500,000 Fibonacci numbers calculation (vector calc): 0.0826 (sec).
    Grand common divisors of 1,000,000 pairs (recursion): 0.192 (sec).
    Creation of a 3,500 x 3,500 Hilbert matrix (matrix calc): 0.101 (sec).
    Creation of a 3,000 x 3,000 Toeplitz matrix (loops): 0.488 (sec).
    Escoufier's method on a 60 x 60 matrix (mixed): 0.406 (sec).
# Matrix calculation benchmarks (5 tests):
    Creation, transp., deformation of a 5,000 x 5,000 matrix: 0.162 (sec).
    2,500 x 2,500 normal distributed random matrix^1,000: 0.0794 (sec).
    Sorting of 7,000,000 random values: 0.481 (sec).
    2,500 x 2,500 cross-product matrix (b = a' * a): 7.53 (sec).
    Linear regr. over a 5,000 x 500 matrix (c = a \ b'): 0.629 (sec).
# Matrix function benchmarks (5 tests):
    Cholesky decomposition of a 3,000 x 3,000 matrix: 4.13 (sec).
    Determinant of a 2,500 x 2,500 random matrix: 1.48 (sec).
    Eigenvalues of a 640 x 640 random matrix: 0.349 (sec).
    FFT over 2,500,000 random values: 0.0689 (sec).
    Inverse of a 1,600 x 1,600 random matrix: 1.16 (sec).


I wonder what changes if you update R on the Intel machine to R 4.4.0 and re-run. (+1)

The issue was that devtools::session_info was wrongly telling me that I was using the Acclerate BLAS while I was in RStudio, but then told me I was using the standard R BLAS when I ran the script outside of RStudio.
When I relinked the Accelerate BLAS using the instructions here: https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/RMacOSX-FAQ.html#Which-BLAS-is-used-and-how-can-it-be-changed_003f
the poor matrix performance went away.
New results on M3 Macbook
# Programming benchmarks (5 tests):
    3,500,000 Fibonacci numbers calculation (vector calc): 0.0742 (sec).
    Grand common divisors of 1,000,000 pairs (recursion): 0.208 (sec).
    Creation of a 3,500 x 3,500 Hilbert matrix (matrix calc): 0.0971 (sec).
    Creation of a 3,000 x 3,000 Toeplitz matrix (loops): 0.454 (sec).
    Escoufier's method on a 60 x 60 matrix (mixed): 0.261 (sec).
# Matrix calculation benchmarks (5 tests):
    Creation, transp., deformation of a 5,000 x 5,000 matrix: 0.169 (sec).
    2,500 x 2,500 normal distributed random matrix^1,000: 0.0767 (sec).
    Sorting of 7,000,000 random values: 0.479 (sec).
    2,500 x 2,500 cross-product matrix (b = a' * a): 0.0477 (sec).
    Linear regr. over a 5,000 x 500 matrix (c = a \ b'): 0.0054 (sec).
# Matrix function benchmarks (5 tests):
    Cholesky decomposition of a 3,000 x 3,000 matrix: 0.0582 (sec).
    Determinant of a 2,500 x 2,500 random matrix: 0.0948 (sec).
    Eigenvalues of a 640 x 640 random matrix: 0.0964 (sec).
    FFT over 2,500,000 random values: 0.0658 (sec).
    Inverse of a 1,600 x 1,600 random matrix: 0.0736 (sec).



Why not rely on sessionInfo().
